# how add item in choice when i press button?

Tags: java, swing

I want to add an item in choice when I press button...

means suppose when I press button "hello" this name of button should be added into my choice(let say it's object is `ch`),so in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` method I write like `ch.add(ae.getActionCommand());`...

When I do this at that time "hello" is added into my choice but when I logout from my project and again login then it disappear....

What to do I do not know?

Actually I want this in my project based on **GUI**&**Java** and **DBMS**...

Comment: Take a moment to edit your question so it's *clear* and *concise*.

Comment: are you saving it in your database

Comment: Is this GUI made using Swing, AWT, SWT..?  Do you mean you want to store the state of the choices into a DB when the app. closes, and restore them from the DB at start-up?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html). It is a standard mechanism to manage preference and configuration data.